# Having a lot of trouble provisioning my iphone for development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist, provisioning

I tried repairing disk permissions to try and get rid of a 100013 error I was getting on a development certificate, left the computer alone for the weekend. When I came back and tried to build my program I got an error :
com.apple.tools.product-pkg-utility: error reading property list '/Users/Kevin/Desktop/iProspectLite/Entitlement.plist' - property list has no object.
How do I fix this? the documentation provided by other people and apple is overly confusing for a novice developer such as myself.

Answer (score 0):

The best documentation is inside the developers portal - right where you create the provisioning profile (a step-by-step explanation).

I have used it few times in the beginning until I got used to this process...

Comment: i tried following all the steps inside the developers portal, but still I have a crapload of errors.

Comment: Do have an Entitlements.plist file in the location where the error states?

Comment: yes I do. its the Entitlement file that I found out needs to be there in order to put the app on my iphone (or so I've been told). Ive tried deleting it and making a new one, but nothing doing.

Comment: What do you mean "you've been told"? The Entitlements.plist file is one of the steps in the step-by-step explanation in developers portal. Are you sure you've walked through all the steps? There is also a change to the default Entitlements file that you have to do. Have you done it?

Comment: OK nevermind. I had my brother try and do it, and he had to delete all the keychains from the computer, re-add them, and follow the instructions on the dev portal to get it to work. Took him about 3 hrs solid tinkering, but he got it done.